# How to use JSON to get data on website in android?

Tags: java, android, database, json

I have an application in android which is it will take database on website. I already created HttpGet, HttpURLConnection, and HttpClient in my coding, is that enough? and how to start select data on my website database?

Answer (score 1):

I recently just learned how to download and parse data (XML and JSON) from a website in android. I'd highly recommend reading this article

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-andbene1/

it's quite thorough and explains the concepts really well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (Google's JSON library).  It's really pretty easy to use, and reasonably well documented.